# Adding select user field in com_content to assign article to specific user

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, com-content, custom-field

I am working on a student management system.
How can I add extra select field (e.g. select user, select class.) to com_content, so that I can assign the article to the specific student (e.g. mark-sheet) and the parent can also see his child student data (mark-sheet)?

I have created user groups and access levels for all classes. For example a student log-in and can see his result but cannot see any other student's result, and same works for parent.

Answer (score 2):

This article shows you how to do that 
http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-dec-2014/item/2402-adding-fields-to-com-content-the-smart-way & https://github.com/katalystsol/plg_content_ksextras

Basically it involves create a custom cotent plugin that hooks into Joomla's onContentPrepareForm() and onContentPrepareData() methods.

here's a copy of the plugin's code

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright Copyright 2014 Katalyst Solutions, LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later;
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

/**
 * This is a custom testimonial plugin class to add additional fields to com_content to allow it to be used for reviews/testimonials 
 * and output the data using schema.org/Review. It will add an additional tab called Testimonial
 */
class plgContentKSExtras extends JPlugin
{
    /** var string Name of the plugin */
    protected $plg_name;

    /** var array List of fields to look for in the $attribs */
    protected $ksfields;

    /** var string The organization name */
    protected $organization;

    /** var string Organization Type used for Schema.org */
    protected $organization_type;

    /** var string Category */
    protected $category;

    /** var boolean Limit plugin to selected category */
    protected $limit_to_category;

    /** var boolean Include child categories */
    protected $include_child_categories;

    public function __construct(& $subject, $config)
    {
        // We only want to use this with com_content
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $option = $jinput->get('option');
        if ($option <> 'com_content')
        {
            return true;
        }

        parent::__construct($subject, $config);

        $this->plg_name                 = 'ksextras';
        $this->ksfields                 = $this->setKSFields();

        // Get the plugin parameters
        $this->organization             = $this->params->get('organization');
        $this->organization_type        = $this->params->get('organization_type');
        $this->category                 = $this->params->get('category');
        $this->limit_to_category        = $this->params->get('limit_to_category');
        $this->include_child_categories = $this->params->get('include_child_categories');

        // Load the language file for the plugin
        $this->loadLanguage();
    }

    /**
     * Set the values for the ksfields array
     * These should correspond to the fields in extras/testimonial.xml
     * These should not use the same name as any com_content attribs fields
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function setKSFields()
    {
        $ksfields = array (
            'testimonial_by',
            'author_job_title',
            'author_affiliation',
            'rating',
            'author_address',
            'author_locality',
            'author_region',
            'author_postal_code',
            'author_url',
        );

        return $ksfields;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the form to add to the article edit
     *
     * @param object $form
     * @param object $data
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
    {
        // If the category id is set, then check if the plugin should be limited to a specific category
        if (!empty($data->catid))
        {
            $this->getChildCategories($data->catid);
            if ($this->limit_to_category && !$this->checkCategory($data->catid))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (!($form instanceof JForm))
        {
            $this->_subject->setError('JERROR_NOT_A_FORM');
            return false;
        }

        // Check that we are manipulating a valid form
        $name = $form->getName();

        if (!in_array($name, array('com_content.article')))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Add the extra fields to the form
        JForm::addFormPath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/extras');
        $form->loadFile('testimonial', false);

        // Load the data from table into the form
        $articleId = isset($data->id) ? $data->id : 0;

        // If there is already an $articleId, then the article is in edit mode 
        // and we need to retrieve the data from the database
        if ($articleId)
        {
            // Load the data from the database
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select('article_id, data');
            $query->from('#__content_ksextras');
            $query->where('article_id = '.$db->Quote($articleId));
            $db->setQuery($query);

            $attribs = $db->loadObject();

            // Check for a database error.
            if ($db->getErrorNum())
            {
                $this->_subject->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
                return false;
            }

            // json_decode the data
            if (!empty($attribs->data))
            {
                $ksdata = json_decode(json_decode($attribs->data));
            }
        }

        // fill in the form with data
        if(isset($attribs))
        {
            foreach ($this->ksfields as $ksfield)
            {
                $data->attribs[$ksfield] = isset($ksdata->$ksfield) ? $ksdata->$ksfield : '';
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Runs on content preparation.
     * Called after the data for a JForm has been retrieved.
     *
     * @param   string  $context    The context for the data
     * @param   object  $data       An object containing the data for the form.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function onContentPrepareData($context, $data)
    {
        if (is_object($data))
        {
            $articleId = isset($data->id) ? $data->id : 0;

            if ($articleId > 0)
            {
                // Load the data from the database
                $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                $query = $db->getQuery(true);
                $query->select('data');
                $query->from('#__content_ksextras');
                $query->where('article_id = '.$db->Quote($articleId));
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $results = $db->loadObject();

                // Check for a database error
                if ($db->getErrorNum())
                {
                    $this->_subject->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
                    return false;
                }

                $ksdata = (count($results)) ? json_decode(json_decode($results->data)) : new stdClass;

                // Merge the data
                $data->attribs = array();

                foreach ($this->ksfields as $ksfield)
                {
                    $data->attribs[$ksfield] = isset($ksdata->$ksfield) ? $ksdata->$ksfield : '';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Load the form
                JForm::addFormPath(dirname(__FILE__).'/extras');
                $form = new JForm('com_content.article');
                $form->loadFile('testimonial', false);

                // Merge the default values
                $data->attribs = array();
                foreach ($form->getFieldset('attribs') as $field)
                {
                    $data->attribs[] = array($field->fieldname, $field->value);
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Fires after content save post event hook to save custom data into #__content_ksextras
     *
     * @param $context
     * @param $data
     * @param $isNew
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function onContentAfterSave($context, $data, $isNew)
    {
        // Check if we are manipulating a valid form
        if (!in_array($context, array('com_content.article')))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Get the article id or set to 0 if new article (it should have an id at this point)
        $articleId = isset($data->id) ? $data->id : 0;

        // Get the attributes
        $attribs = json_decode($data->attribs);

        // Pull out the extra fields to insert into the table
        $ksattribs = array();
        foreach ($this->ksfields as $ksfield)
        {
            $ksattribs[$ksfield] = isset($attribs->$ksfield) ? $attribs->$ksfield : '';
        }
        $ksattribs = json_encode($ksattribs);

        // Get the database object
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        // Check for an existing entry
        $db->setQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #__content_ksextras WHERE article_id = '.$articleId);
        $res = $db->loadResult();

        // Updating or adding
        if (!empty($res)) // updating record
        {
            $this->updateRecord($ksattribs, $articleId);
        }
        else // Adding a new record
        {
            $this->insertRecord($ksattribs, $articleId);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Remove the data when the article is deleted
    *
    * Method is called before (after?) article data is deleted from the database
    *
    * @param string The context for the content passed to the plugin.
    * @param object The data relating to the content that was deleted.
    *
    * @return bool
    * @throws JException
    */
    public function onContentAfterDelete($context, $data)
    {
         // get the article id
        $articleId = isset($data->id) ? (int) $data->id : 0;

        if ($articleId)
        {
            try
            {
                $db = JFactory::getDbo();

                $db->setQuery('DELETE FROM #__content_ksextras WHERE article_id = '.$articleId );

                if (!$db->execute()) {
                    throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
                }
            }
            catch (JException $e)
            {
                $this->_subject->setError($e->getMessage());

                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * The first stage in preparing the content for output
     *
     * @param $context
     * @param $article
     * @param $params
     * @param $page
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
        if (!isset($article->testimonial) || !count($article->testimonial))
        {
            return;
        }

        // add extra css for table
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        //$doc->addStyleSheet(JURI::base(true).'/plugins/content/ksextras/extras/ksextras.css');

        // construct a result table on the fly   
        jimport('joomla.html.grid');
        $table = new JGrid();

        // Create columns
        $table->addColumn('attr')->addColumn('value');   

        // populate
        $rownr = 0;
        foreach ($article->testimonial as $attr => $value)
        {
            $table->addRow(array('class' => 'row'.($rownr % 2)));
            $table->setRowCell('attr', $attr);
            $table->setRowCell('value', $value);
            $rownr++;
        }

        // wrap table in a classed <div>
        $suffix = $this->params->get('testimonialclass_sfx', 'testimonial');
        $html = '<div class="'.$suffix.'">'.(string)$table.'</div>';

        $article->text = $html.$article->text;
    }

     /**
    * Insert a new record into the database
    *
    * @param $attribs our extra fields in object form
    * @param $articleId the article id we are relating the fields to
    *
    * @return bool
    * @throws Exception
    */
    public function insertRecord($attribs, $articleId)
    {
        // Get a db connection.
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        // Create a new query object.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Insert columns.
        $columns = array('article_id', 'data', 'created', 'created_by');

        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $created_by = $user->id;
        $created = JFactory::getDate()->toSql();

        // Insert values.
        $values = array(
            $articleId,
            $db->quote(json_encode($attribs)),
            $db->quote($created),
            $created_by,
        );

        // insert query
        $query
            ->insert($db->quoteName('#__content_ksextras'))
            ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
            ->values(implode(',', $values));

        // set the query
        $db->setQuery($query);

        // execute, throw an exception if we have a problem
        if (!$db->execute()) {
            throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
        }

        return true;
    }


    /**
    * Update record function
    *
    * @param $attribs requires object of attributes from form
    * @param $articleId id of the article we are relating to
    *
    * @return bool
    * @throws Exception
    */
    protected function updateRecord($attribs, $articleId)
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        // Create a new query object.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $conditions = array(
            'article_id='.$articleId,
        );

        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $modified_by = $user->id;
        $modified = JFactory::getDate()->toSql();

        // Fields to update.
        $fields = array(
            'data='.$db->quote(json_encode($attribs)),
            'modified='.$db->quote($modified),
            'modified_by='.$modified_by,
        );

        // update query
        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__content_ksextras'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

        // set the query
        $db->setQuery($query);

        // execute, throw an exception if we have a problem
        if (!$db->execute()) {
            throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check the article category against the category selected by the plugin
     *
     * @param integer   $article_cat        The category of the article
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function checkCategory($article_cat)
    {
        if ($this->category == $article_cat)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Need to check if the current category's parent or grand-parent 
        // is the category selected for this plugin
        if ($this->include_child_categories)
        {
            $parents = $this->getParentCategories($article_cat);
            if (in_array($this->category, $parents))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of the category children
     *
     * @param integer   $catId  The id of the category to check
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getChildCategories($catId)
    {
        jimport('joomla.application.categories');
        $categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content');
        $cat        = $categories->get($catId);
        $children   = $cat->getChildren();
        $childCats  = array();

        foreach ($children as $child)
        {
            $childCats[] = $child->id;
        }

        return $childCats;
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of the category parent(s)
     *
     * @param integer   $catId  The id of the category to check
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getParentCategories($catId)
    {
        $parentCats = array();

        jimport('joomla.application.categories');
        $categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content');
        $cat        = $categories->get($catId);

        // Check the parent_id. If it is an integer > 0, update the array and 
        // check for a parent_id of the parent... Only going up 2 levels...
        if ((int)$cat->parent_id)
        {
            $parentCats[]   = $cat->parent_id;
            $parent         = $cat->getParent();
            if ((int) $parent->parent_id)
            {
                $parentCats[] = $parent->parent_id;
            }
        }

        return $parentCats;
    }

}
```

````

Comment: thanks for your code and explanation #Rob . I will test it and comment back. i think you are trying to say that i have to make a custom plugin but which variable do i use to show user list in the com_content to assign article to. actually i have referred to that code before and the choose country list is the step to my answer but i don't know how to put user select field to assign article to student and parent.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I see its a bit more complex than I thought with respect to the access control. Personally I probably wouldn't use com_content but rather Fabrik to build this. (disclaimer I'm one of the core coders for fabrik) - It would allow you to build lists of entries/articles on which you can create list pre-filters specifying  things like "only show students own entries"

Comment: Excited to know that you are one of the core developers of "Fabrik". i haven't use Fabrik but have heard a lot about that extension.will it create custom fields in com_content such as "Student-name, Student-ID"  or it has its own procedure ? and secondly will it gives the option to add access control to articles and other component and modules. Thanks #Rob for your helpful information.